# Is there a refactor "block lambda to separate method" feature?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I often use lambdas, but sometimes they tend to grow over time. Starting with...

```
someMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> doStuff());
```

.. I often end up with something like:

```
someMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> {
    if (!doStuff()) {
        displayError("Couldn't do stuff.");
    }
});
```

I don't think block lambdas make for elegant code, so I usually refactor it to this:

```
someMenuItem.setOnAction(event -> userPerformsDoStuff());
```

Along with the method:

```
public void userPerformsDoStuff() {
    if (!doStuff()) {
        displayError("Couldn't do stuff.");
    }
}
```

Copying the code around in my file and tidying up all the forgotten parentheses and semicolons is quite cumbersome and I would love to have my IDE [[image]intellij-idea](/questions/tagged/intellij-idea) do the refactoring for me.

It sounds so trivial and useful, that I find it hard to believe such a feature doesn't yet exist. Have I just not looked hard enough or do I have to create a feature request?

---

<sub>Please note that usually I use `Exception`s for error handling and the given example was chosen for brevity.</sub>

Comment: Can't you just select the body of the lambda, and extract to method (Ctrl-Alt-m)? I am pretty sure I did exactly that earlier today.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes, you can. Well, I have no excuse for not thinking about that. Can you write a short answer so I can accept it and quietly bury this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the body of the lambda, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to extract it to a method.